# Phonegap API not defined / Plugin error

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, cordova

I'm currently building an Application with PhoneGap(3.3). When i try to get the API to work i always get the error:

for example:
"Cannot call method 'vibrate' of undefined

What i did:

```
phonegap create appname com.myname.appname appname
phonegap local build android
phonegap plugin add XXXXXX plugin path (gave me response that plugin was installed correctly)
```

modified my index.html to call vibrate when the device is loaded

```
     function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
    }
```

But i still cant get the phonegap api to work since i get the error the method is not defined. Anybody got a solution for this or am i just plain dumb.

Regards

Comment: did you run `phonegap local build android` again after installing the plugin?

Comment: You need to add the plugin first before doing the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check that you have installed both notification plugins:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration
```

AND make sure that after you install the plugins you run the build command again:

```
phonegap local build android
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i missed, i just installed the plugins without rebuilding. Stupid me. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying my code to native platforms, I often don't include links to the cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js.  Make sure you've added those in before you prepare your code. It's an easy step to miss.